# Mid 2012 Apple MacBook Pro 13in

Tags: macbook-pro

Need help!! My MacBook was working perfectly until I tried to factory reset it through disk Utility. I’m not sure what I deleted but now when I turn it on a little folder pops up with a question mark and nothing else. But if I turn it on and hold down the “option” key it pulls up a scroll to connect to WiFi and then after that it brings up a “internet recovery” tab, then it brings me to “OS X utilities”. Not sure what to do from here, I don’t want to take it somewhere to be fixed if I can fix it with someone’s help, thank in advance

Comment: I’m curious...i’ve been seeing the phrase “factory reset” associated to Mac computers quite a bit of recent.  Where did you get the instructions to do this “reset”?  I ask because there’s really no such thing - its not a phone.

Answer (score 2):

It seems likely that your "factory reset" was actually you deleting macOS and everything else from the disk on your Mac. Hopefully you had a backup as doing this erased *EVERYTHING* on the computer.

The way forward is to use internet recovery to reinstall macOS and then you can restore your applications and documents, pictures, etc. using whatever backup you have standing by for just such an event.